# Entity from ManyToOne lazy relation not being loaded in different class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities A and B, where A has a @ManyToOne lazy relation with B. I have fetched A inside a transaction and passed that fetched entity to another class for the mapping of its properties to some dto. For some reason, when a have a access like A.getB().getProperty() on the original class of the transaction, it fetched the property value with no problems, bu when a have the same access being done in the mapper class, the property value returns null. Why is that? Is this some sort of bad practice?

```
@Entity(name="domain.service.A")
@ODataEntity(id = "a")
@Table(name="a")
public class A implements Persistable<java.util.UUID> {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b")
    private B b;
}
```

```
@Entity(name="domain.service.B")
@ODataEntity(id = "b")
@Table(name="b")
public class B implements Persistable<java.util.UUID> {
    @Column(name = "property")
    private String property;
}
```

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
   @Autowired
   Repository repository;
   @Autowired
   Mapper mapper;

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public void execute() {
      var entity = repository.findById(someId);
      // returns value
      // entity.getB().getProperty()
      mapper.map(entity);
   }
}
```

```
@Component
public class Mapper {

   public void map(A entity) {
      var propertyValue = entity.getB().getProperty()
      // propertyValue == null
   }
}
```

Comment: Why manually map?

Comment: There is some logical condition in this mapping that i didnt include in the sample code. Is something like: if fieldA is null the map to ENUM_A else if fieldA is not null and fieldB has a certain value map to ENUM_B or else map to ENUM_C.

Answer (score 0):

[ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/) can help you!

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
EntityDTO entityDTO = modelMapper.map(entity, EntityDTO.class);
```